# C# Unable to print euro symbol into a file (when opening with Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, utf-8, httpcontent

I have a problem with a get method into a  web api controller. This method returns a HttpResponseMessage object which has a HttpContent with a csv file, which contains euro symbols. When the method returns the file, the euro symbol isn't printed.
The code of the method is the following:

```
string export = ... //string with fields separed by ';' and with euro symbol
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
Byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(export);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Export.csv" };
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = export.Length;
response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
return response;
```

When I open the file, the euro symbol doesn't appear correctly.
Could you give me an answer?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What means "doesn't appear correctly"? Is it there? Maybe you are opening file with wrong encoding?

Comment: try with by setting `response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Utf8; response.Charset = encoding.BodyName; `

Comment: I see 'â‚¬' instead of '€'. I'm opening the file with Excel.

Comment: response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding is a read only property

Comment: I notice that If I open the file with Notepad, the  euro symbol is displayed correctly. The problem is that I want to open the file with Excel, is there a way to set Excel cells encoding?

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned, this doesn't work in Excel as the € sign isn't shown properly (although it is in any plain text editor).

```
[HttpPost("csv")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCvsReport()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var content = "12€;3;test";
    var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    response.Content = new StringContent(content, encoding , "text/csv");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = yourfile.csv"
    };

    return response;
}
```

I found the following solutions that seem to work properly.

### Use Windows-1252 encoding

It seems that by using [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding Excel is able to correctly interpret the € symbol.

```
[HttpPost("csv")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCvsReport()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var content = "12€;3;test";
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

    response.Content = new StringContent(content, encoding , "text/csv");
    ...
}
```

### Prepend the BOM (Byte order mark)

Another solution that works is to append the correct BOM like this:

```
[HttpPost("csv")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCvsReport()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var content = "12€;3;test";
    var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    content = encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF }) + content;    

    response.Content = new StringContent(content, encoding , "text/csv");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = yourfile.csv"
    };

    return response;
}
```

Take the solution you like most.

Comment: thanks using Windows-1252 encoding just saved me a bit of trouble

Comment: That answer should have got more upvotes. That is the only proper explanation I found after a day of research about the content headers and encodings. Thank you!

Comment: Windows-1252 fixed the issue for me. Thanks !